# Compile to byte code takes up too much memory

Tags: python, memory, dictionary, bytecode

I need to import a very large dictionary into python and I'm running into some unexpected memory bottlenecks. The dictionary has the form,

```
d = {(1,2,3):(1,2,3,4), (2,5,6)=(4,2,3,4,5,6), ... }
```

So each key is a 3-tuple and each value is a relatively small tuple of arbitrary size (probably never more than 30 elements). What makes the dictionary large is the number of keys. A smaller example of what  I'm working with has roughly 247257 keys. I generate this dictionary through a simulation so I can write out a text file that defines this dictionary and for the example I just mentioned this is a 94MB file. The bottleneck I am running into is that the initial compile to python byte code eats up about 14GB of ram. So the first time I import the dictionary I see the RAM usage spike up and after a good 10 seconds everything is loaded. If the .pyc file is already generated the import is nearly instant. Using pympler, I've determined that this dictionary is only about 200 MB in memory. What is the deal here? Do I have any other options on how get this dictionary loaded into python or at least compiled to byte code. I'm running the generating simulations in C++ and I can't write files an whatever format I need. Are there any options there (python libraries, etc.)? I'm interfacing with some software that needs this data as a dictionary so please no other suggestions in that realm. Also just in case you are wondering, I have defined the dictionary in the text file like the definition above as well as like so,

```
d = {}
d[1,2,3] = (1,2,3,4)
d[2,5,6] = (4,2,3,4,5,6)
...
```

Both give the same memory spike in compile to byte code. In fact, the second one seems to be slightly worse, which is surprising to me. There's got to be some way to tame the amount of ram the initial compile needs. It seems like it should somehow be able to do the compile one key-value pair at a time. Any ideas?

Other info:
using python 2.6.5

Comment: are you separating your data in multiple lines of your file?

Comment: I've tried both ways: 1)a single giant dictionary definition, 2) multiple lines of d[key] =  value

Comment: why don't you write the dict to a file using `pprint.pformat` and uses `eval` or `ast.literal_eval` on loading?

Comment: That worked well on 60MB matrices I was working last week...

Comment: I could be wrong but it sounds likes these are python functions. And using them would involve loading the dictionary into python first, which is exactly the issue. Or are these C++ suggestions?

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood the issue... But you can write the dict on file already in Python format and just evaluate it

Comment: Why aren't you saving this with `shelve`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that your big compile spike happens when you do "import module_containing_humungous_dict_statement".  Then it doesn't matter if you've got just one statement or 247257 separate assignment statements, the whole module will still get compiled at once.  You could try using the separate-assignment-statement form, and then opening the file, reading one line at a time, and exec'ing it.  Then you will only be compiling one line at a time. Will probably take a while.

Comment: This method was able to get past the memory spike and it was actually on par with the speed of the python compile (if not slightly faster). This may be the best option. However, when attempting to pickle the dictionary, the memory spike occurs again. I just wish there was a way to save the dictionary in some low level form that python could quickly read in again. Thoughts?

Comment: I'm sorry, I take that last comment back. This DID also overcome the memory spike when pickling the dictionary. So just to recap, both importing the dictionary file and pickling gave separate memory spikes (14+ GB). Note, however, that the pickling was not needed as long as a .pyc file was created from the import, since this could now be quickly imported without a large memory overhead. I just did this to double check things. HOWEVER, if I loop through each line in the file and exec(line), then pickle, I never see a memory usage of more than 600MB (compared to the 14GB spike).

Comment: Then, of course, once the dictionary is pickled it can very easily be loaded back in with no memory spike. I would LOVE to hear anyone's explanation as to why this happens.

Comment: Well unpickling doesn't require any actual *compiling*, just parsing of the pickled data into the actual objects. So at that level, probably very much akin to the exec-one-line-at-a-time approach.

Comment: I agree, I just find it strange about the initial pickling, not the unpickling.

Comment: Basically, I'm good to go once I have the object pickled or compiled to bytecode. It's just getting there without using an obserd amount of RAM. But this seemed to have solved the problem so thank you :)

Answer (score 3):

I guess the problem is that while parsing your file an enormous syntax tree is made with a small overhead for each element that all add up. Once the bytecode is generated the syntax tree is no longer necessary and dumped, resulting in your 200MB data.

Have you tried storing the data in a seperate file in the following format and then dynamically load it in python?

```
1,2,3=1,2,3
2,5,6=4,2,3,4,5,6
```

The Python script should look something like this:

```
file = open("filename")
d = {}

for line in file:
    key, val = line.split("=")
    key = tuple(key.split(","))
    d[key] = tuple(val.split(","))

file.close()
```

Answer (score 2):

http://docs.python.org/library/shelve.html

Answer (score 0):

I suspect creating the list to use as a key is what is expensive.  Define a function that takes the three parts of the triple as input and returns a pipe delimited string.  Use that as your key.

Comment: This idea didn't seem to solve the problem. Still had the same memory spike during compile.

Answer (score 0):

The way I read your question, you are generating Python source in your simulator, and the generated source has the contents of the giant dictionary hard-coded.  If that is true, then you might as easily generate this:

```
def giantdict():
  d0 = {(1, 2): (3, 4), (3, 4): (5, 6), ...}  # first 1000 key/value pairs here
  d1 = {(1, 2): (3, 4), (3, 4): (5, 6), ...}  # next 1000 key/value pairs
  d2 = {(1, 2): (3, 4), (3, 4): (5, 6), ...}  # next 1000 key/value pairs
  d3 = {(1, 2): (3, 4), (3, 4): (5, 6), ...}  # next 1000 key/value pairs
  # ... until you're done
  bigd = d0
  bigd.update(d1)
  del d1
  bigd.update(d2)
  del d2
  # ... continue updating with all the dN dictionaries
  return bigd
```

I'm not sure that this will improve the compile time, but it would be something to try.  If there is a penalty to putting everything in one data structure at compile time, splitting it up and assembling the pieces at run time may work around it.

While this kind of code (mine or yours) would draw my fury and ire if a human wrote it, I see no need for generated code to be "nice", as long as you **know** that no human will ever need to read it or maintain it.

Comment: This method still had the same memory issue, even without the creation of the single big dictionary at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a class that uses a defaultdict for the automatic nesting of indexed values, with some special `__getitem__` and `__setitem__` methods to accept tuples as arguments:

```
from collections import defaultdict

defdict3level = (lambda : defaultdict(lambda : 
                            defaultdict( lambda : 
                                defaultdict(tuple))))

class dict3level(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.defdict = defdict3level()

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        if isinstance(key, tuple):
            if len(key)==3:
                return self.defdict[key[0]][key[1]][key[2]]
            elif len(key)==2:
                return self.defdict[key[0]][key[1]]
            elif len(key)==1:
                return self.defdict[key[0]]
        else:
            return self.defdict[key]

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        if isinstance(key, tuple) and len(key)==3:
            self.defdict[key[0]][key[1]][key[2]] = value
        else:
            self.defdict[key] = value

    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        return getattr(self.defdict, attr)
```

Now exec all your assignments like before:

```
d = dict3level()
d[1,2,3] = (1,2,3,4)
d[1,2,7] = (3,4,5,6)
d[2,5,6] = (4,2,3,4,5,6)
```

You can still get a specific entry for a specific tuple:

```
# get a specific entry
print d[1,2,3]
```

But you can also navigate your dict by levels:

```
# get all different 0'th index values
print d.keys()

# get all sub values in d[1,2,*]
print d[1,2].keys()
for key in d[1,2]:
    print "d[1,2,%d] = %s" % (key, d[1,2][key])

# no such entry, return empty tuple
print d[1,2,0]
```

Gives:

```
print d[1,2,3] -> (1, 2, 3, 4)
print d.keys() -> [1, 2]
print d[1,2].keys() -> [3, 7]
for key in d[1,2]:... -> 
    d[1,2,3] = (1, 2, 3, 4)
    d[1,2,7] = (3, 4, 5, 6)
print d[1,2,0] -> ()
```

(Don't know how this will affect your memory and/or pickling issues, but the resulting structure has a lot more capability to it.)

Comment: I will try this out and let you know about the memory.

Answer (score 0):

http://bugs.python.org/issue5557